# Function Now in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am trying to find an extended description about the function `Now()`, which returns time. On the official FreePascal site is this description:

> Now returns the current date and time. It is equivalent to Date+Time.

I am looking for time which is measured from the epoch January, 1, 1970 00:00:00 in FreePascal.

Can you help me?

Comment: The integral part of [TDateTime](https://wiki.freepascal.org/TDateTime) is the number of days since 12/30/1899. If you want unix time, see [DateTimeToUnix](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/dateutils/datetimetounix.html).

Answer (score 4):

Pascal has a very different idea of the "Start of Time" one that I think is more mathematically simple, as well as just makes better sense. At any rate, if I understand your question right, I think you are looking for something like a Unix Timestamp value?

This is how you would get that in FreePascal:

```
uses sysutils, dateutils;

function GetUnixNow() : Int64;
begin
  Result := DateTimeToUnix(Now());
end;
```

Calling this function will return a 64bit Integer that is the equivalent to `(unsigned long)time(NULL);` in C11

Comment: Freepascal's and Delphi's `TDateTime` format is the windows OLE standard, so not so exotic as one might think.

Comment: Delphi and Lazarus/freepascal use register, not stdcall. Most reasons for calling conventions are extremely historical (and often also depend on what Intel was advocating as ideal at the time). Making pedigree decisions on that is difficult.    Cdecl is an exception, due to the way how varargs are originized in C.

Comment: Thank you @MarcovandeVoort for the correction. I have **removed** my incorrect previous comment, so it is not confusing people, especially if they don't see your comment too.